# Core Data entries not updating correctly in swift3

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

I have a core data entries with certain keys and values stored in the database fetched from API . Now i want to update some core data entries with the updated values So for this i am using the code as below:

```
    func updateAllRecords(responseArray: [Dictionary<String, String>]) {
    for settingsObject in responseArray {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let keys = settingsObject.flatMap() { $0.0 as? String }
      let values = settingsObject.flatMap(){ $0.1 as? String}
      let request = NSFetchRequest<ApplicationSettings>(entityName: "ApplicationSettings")

      do {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let searchResults = try context.fetch(request)

        for settingsKeys in searchResults {

        if  keys.contains(settingsKeys.key!) {
            settingsKeys.value = values[1]
            try context.save()
          }
        }

      } catch {
        print ("There was an error")
      }

    } else {

        }
  }
  }
}
```

I am calling this function from viewcontroller like this:

```
 var dicArray = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
                  let dic1 = ["IS_CIVIL_ID_MANDATORY": "Smith", "TIME_IN_MIN_BEFORE_ENABLING_START_TRIP": "Robert"]
                  dicArray.append(dic1)
                  CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.updateAllRecords(responseArray: dicArray)
```

But the entries in the table is not updating correctly for the keys. It is storing the same value for both the keys. See below:

[image: Data base]

Where i am wrong in this code? Why same values are stored for the keys?

Comment: settingsKeys.value = values[1] it is static  replace values[1] with your value

Comment: hello @Chelsea is any doubt in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made mistake here
`settingsKeys.value = values[1]` here 1 is static

I think you don't require values array separate
just replace this code with my code

```
for settingsKeys in searchResults {

        if  keys.contains(settingsKeys.key!) 
         {
            settingsKeys.updateValue(settingObject[settingsKeys.key!], forKey:settingsKeys.key!)
            try context.save()
          }
        }

      }
```

For Demo Example

```
func updateAllRecords(responseArray: [Dictionary<String, String>])
{
    for settingsObject in responseArray
    {

            var dic2 = ["IS_CIVIL_ID_MANDATORY": "xyz", "TIME_IN_MIN_BEFORE_ENABLING_START_TRIP": "xyz"]
            let keys = settingsObject.flatMap() {$0.0}
            let values = settingsObject.flatMap(){$0.1}
            let settingKeys = dic2.flatMap() {$0.0}

            for settingsKey in settingKeys
            {

                dic2.updateValue(settingsObject[settingsKey]!, forKey: settingsKey)

            }
            print(keys)
        print(dic2)
    }
}
var dicArray = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
let dic1 = ["IS_CIVIL_ID_MANDATORY": "Smith", "TIME_IN_MIN_BEFORE_ENABLING_START_TRIP": "Robert"]
dicArray.append(dic1)
updateAllRecords(responseArray: dicArray)
```

**Output**

["TIME_IN_MIN_BEFORE_ENABLING_START_TRIP": "Robert", "IS_CIVIL_ID_MANDATORY": "Smith"]

Comment: @ChelseaShawra i have created demo for it check "xyz" is replaced with corresponding values

Comment: you can also change your line with this `settingsKeys.value = settingsObject[settingsKeys.key!]!`

Comment: okk if [Dictionary<String, String>] is replaced with array of dictionaries then what can i do?

Comment: sorry i cant understand can you please update question  with what you exactly want to update, with input data and your expected output